# Requesting information about obfuscated text

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am going to recreate obfuscated text in an online chat client I am making, and I want to know some information about the text so I can recreate it properly.

1. How often does the text cycle to its next generation of random text?
2. What characters specifically are used in obfuscation, and are they formatted in any special way?
3. (optional) Is there already a JavaScript tool available on the web that I can use to recreate obfuscation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It probably changes once per frame, but I haven't verified that.

Comment: Another good question: 4. Does the obfuscated text depend on the normal text in any way, apart from length?

Comment: 2. The characters used for obfuscation are mostly random characters from the english char set of the game, in the 'font' texture library. [Check here](https://imgur.com/a/xWvspCa) for accented.png, ascii.png, and nonlatin_european.png. Some characters like i, l and whitespace are classified as 'thin' and use distinguishably thinner characters.

Comment: @AMJ Is there a copy-pastable version of that charset?